# Python: How to use multiple delimiters to split commas, colons, and letters in a row

Tags: python, delimiter

Here is a sample of my data (and there are a lot of rows of this data in my csv file) and I need a program that can separate the hyphens, colons, and the letter "T" so that I can print out the rows with my desired day (e.g. the 31st of December). I already have a code that can filter out the year and the month, but I am currently having trouble splitting the T/setting the T as a delimiter.

AC2_AC1,382,3,2015-12-31T22:40:00-05

```
import csv

desiredMonth = 12
with open('extractedStreet2015.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    content = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in content:
        month = int(row[3].split('-')[1])
        if month == desiredMonth:
            print(row)
```

How can I write a code so that I can also split the colons and the letter "T"?
(P.S. I'm new to Python so an explanation would be greatly appreciated)

EDITED

When I try running the program below:

```
import csv
import isodate

desiredHour = 12

with open('bt_2015.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    content = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in content:
        date = isodate.parse_datetime(content[3])
        if date.hour == desiredHour:
            print(row[1])
```

This message appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\hour.py", line 10, in <module>
    date = isodate.parse_datetime(content[3])
TypeError: '_csv.reader' object is not subscriptable
```

What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: do you realize your date/time is a standard iso 8601 formatted string

Comment: use the `datetime` module to parse your date-string.

Comment: sorry, I didn't realize, like I said, I'm new to programming (just started a week ago)

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
import isodate
data = 'AC2_AC1,382,3,2015-12-31T22:40:00-05'
parts = data.split(',')
isodate.parse_datetime(parts[3])
datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 31, 22, 40, tzinfo=<FixedOffset '-05'>)
```

now you have a standard python datetime object

Comment: you can, but `isodate` handles all iso 8601 format variations.

Comment: How do I get isodate?

Comment: assuming you have pip: `pip install isodate`

Comment: I don't think I have pip

Comment: installing pip: https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/

Comment: How would I import a csv file in this program?

Comment: dont you mean `parse_datetime(row[3])` instead of `parse_datetime(content[3])`

Answer (score 0):

Using your example:

```
# filename: test_data.txt
AC2_AC1,382,3,2015-12-31T22:40:00-05
```

This is what I would do....

```
$ pip install python-dateutil
```

See:  [pip](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/)

See:  [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)

See:  [python-dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# filename: test.py
import csv
from collections import namedtuple

from dateutil import parser

#  I don't know your field names, but maybe you can supply them.
StreetRecord = namedtuple('StreetRecord', 'ac_field, num01, num02, timestamp')


def extract_records(filepath, month):
    """Captures records that match the month

    Args:
        filepath (str): path to file
        month (int): value of month to filter on

    Yields:
        StreetRecord: each street record that matches the month
    """
    with open(filepath, 'r') as stream:
        content = csv.reader(stream, delimiter=',')
        for record_data in content:
            record = StreetRecord(*record_data)
            # example timestamp: 2015-12-31T22:40:00-05
            timestamp = parser.parse(record.timestamp)
            if timestamp.month == month:
                yield record


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for record in extract_records('test_data.txt', 12):
        print(record)
```

Then run it...

```
python test.py
```

And you'll see:

```
StreetRecord(ac_field='AC2_AC1', num01='382', num02='3', timestamp='2015-12-31T22:40:00-05')
```